# Aggregation across different collections (foreign key) - MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

Considering I have **2 collections**.

The first one called **`origin`** has the following documents (excluding the `_id`):

### Origin

```
[
  {
    "Id": "1",
    "Level1": [
      {
        "Id": "1.1",
        "Level2": [
          {
            "Level3": {
              "Id": "1.1.1",
              "Name": "name 1.1.1"
            }
          },
          {
            "Level3": {
              "Id": "1.1.2",
              "Name": "name 1.1.2"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Id": "1.2",
        "Level2": [
          {
            "Level3": {
              "Id": "1.2.1",
              "Name": "name 1.2.1"
            }
          },
          {
            "Level3": {
              "Id": "1.2.2",
              "Name": "name 1.2.2"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    "Level1": [
      {
        "Id": "2.1",
        "Level2": [
          {
            "Level3": {
              "Id": "2.1.1",
              "Name": "name 2.1.1"
            }
          },
          {
            "Level3": {
              "Id": "2.1.2",
              "Name": "name 2.1.2"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Id": "2.2",
        "Level2": [
          {
            "Level3": {
              "Id": "2.2.1",
              "Name": "name 2.2.1"
            }
          },
          {
            "Level3": {
              "Id": "2.2.2",
              "Name": "name 2.2.2"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The second collection is called **`destination`** and has the following documents:

### Destination

```
[
  {
    "Id": "f1",
    "Level1": {
      "Level2": {
        "Id": "1.1.1",
        "Name": "name 1.1.1"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Id": "f2",
    "Level1": {
      "Level2": {
        "Id": "1.1.2",
        "Name": "name 1.1.2"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Id": "f3",
    "Level1": {
      "Level2": {
        "Id": "1.2.1",
        "Name": "name 1.2.1"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Id": "f4",
    "Level1": {
      "Level2": {
        "Id": "1.2.2",
        "Name": "name 1.2.2"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Id": "f5",
    "Level1": {
      "Level2": {
        "Id": "2.1.1",
        "Name": "name 2.1.1"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Id": "f6",
    "Level1": {
      "Level2": {
        "Id": "2.1.2",
        "Name": "name 2.1.2"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Id": "f7",
    "Level1": {
      "Level2": {
        "Id": "2.2.1",
        "Name": "name 2.2.1"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Id": "f8",
    "Level1": {
      "Level2": {
        "Id": "2.2.2",
        "Name": "name 2.2.2"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

### Query

`Level1.Id = "1.1"` on **`origin`**

---

### Logic

Given a `Level1.Id = "1.1"` on **`origin`** collection, I want to get a list of documents from **`destination`** collection where:

`Level1.Level2.Level3 in` **`origin`** `= Level1.Level2 in` **`destination`**

The aggregation query from **`origin`** should "collect" all the `Level1.Level2.Level3` objects (under the matched `Level1.Id`) and use this array to identify the documents in **`destination`** collection.

---

The expected result is:

### Result

```
[
  {
    "Id": "f1",
    "Level1": {
      "Level2": {
        "Id": "1.1.1",
        "Name": "name 1.1.1"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Id": "f2",
    "Level1": {
      "Level2": {
        "Id": "1.1.2",
        "Name": "name 1.1.2"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

How can I accomplish this with an aggregation query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MongoDB, for aggregating the data from different collections we use `$lookup` for that, explore more about lookup [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/).

I have done the lookup query according to your requirements.

```
db.origin.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind:"$Level1"
  },
  {
    $unwind:"$Level1.Level2"
  },
  {
    $lookup:{
      from:"destination",
      let:{
        "level":"$Level1.Level2.Level3"
      },
      pipeline:[
        {
          $match:{
            $expr:{
              $eq:[
                "$Level1.Level2","$$level"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as:"lookups"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind:{
      path:"$lookups",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true
    }
  }
]).pretty()
```

And, for displaying the fields you want in the output you can use the `$project`. for more read [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/).

Hope this will help you :)

**UPDATE**

```
db.destination.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup:{
      from:"origin",
      let:{
        "level":"$Level1.Level2"
      },
      pipeline:[
        {
          $unwind:"$Level1"
        },
        {
          $unwind:"$Level1.Level2"
        },
        {
          $match:{
            $expr:{
              $eq:[
                "$Level1.Level2.Level3","$$level"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as:"lookups"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind:{
      path:"$lookups",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true
    }
  },
  {
    $project:{
      "Id":1,
      "Level1.Level2":"$lookups.Level1.Level2.Level3"
    }
  }
]).pretty()
```

**Output**

```
[
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5e92196a3a5a7fc48b644f67"),
                "Id" : "f1",
                "Level1" : {
                        "Level2" : {
                                "Id" : "1.1.1",
                                "Name" : "name 1.1.1"
                        }
                }
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5e92196a3a5a7fc48b644f68"),
                "Id" : "f2",
                "Level1" : {
                        "Level2" : {
                                "Id" : "1.1.2",
                                "Name" : "name 1.1.2"
                        }
                }
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5e92196a3a5a7fc48b644f69"),
                "Id" : "f3",
                "Level1" : {
                        "Level2" : {
                                "Id" : "1.2.1",
                                "Name" : "name 1.2.1"
                        }
                }
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5e92196a3a5a7fc48b644f6a"),
                "Id" : "f4",
                "Level1" : {
                        "Level2" : {
                                "Id" : "1.2.2",
                                "Name" : "name 1.2.2"
                        }
                }
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5e92196a3a5a7fc48b644f6b"),
                "Id" : "f5",
                "Level1" : {
                        "Level2" : {
                                "Id" : "2.1.1",
                                "Name" : "name 2.1.1"
                        }
                }
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5e92196a3a5a7fc48b644f6c"),
                "Id" : "f6",
                "Level1" : {
                        "Level2" : {
                                "Id" : "2.1.2",
                                "Name" : "name 2.1.2"
                        }
                }
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5e92196a3a5a7fc48b644f6d"),
                "Id" : "f7",
                "Level1" : {
                        "Level2" : {
                                "Id" : "2.2.1",
                                "Name" : "name 2.2.1"
                        }
                }
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5e92196a3a5a7fc48b644f6e"),
                "Id" : "f8",
                "Level1" : {
                        "Level2" : {
                                "Id" : "2.2.2",
                                "Name" : "name 2.2.2"
                        }
                }
        }
]
```

Comment: Shouldn't "from" on "$lookup" be "origin"? what i udnderstand we are create "level" from the "origin  $Level1.Level2.Level3". I think the query is "upside down" or am i seeing it wrong? :)

Comment: Also, if it is as I’m saying I don’t know to make a $project that filters the fields from the $lookup since the query will start with ```db.destination.aggregate``` and the filter is over “origin”

Comment: ```The aggregation query from origin should "collect" all the Level1.Level2.Level3 objects (under the matched Level1.Id) and use this array to identify the documents in destination collection.```

you have asked in question that's why created the query on the origin and did lookup on destination collection.

Comment: BTW I have updated the answer please have a look.
hope it will help you. :)

Comment: Thank's a lot! Sorry not express myself better on the first time

Comment: No worries, I'm glad it helped you. :)